# How can I use a class type and it's derivations as generic key and value for collections?

Tags: generics, kotlin, collections

sorry if there is a solution on here already, could not find it.

I want to use a Map/Dictionary to keep lists of components. All components inherit from the same class. So to keep things tidy I want to use the class as key and have only components of this class in the right list:

```
private val components : Map<KClass<T : IComponent>, List<T>>
```

Example Code:

```
class GameObject
{
    val components : ObjectMap<KClass<out IComponent>, Array<*>> = ObjectMap()

    fun update(deltaTime: Float)
    {
        for(componentFamily in components.values())
        {
            for(component in componentFamily)
            {
                component.update(deltaTime)
            }
        }
    }

    inline fun <reified T : IComponent> get() : T?
    {
        return components.get(T::class)[0] // This does not work - it returns Any?, not T?
    }
}
```

Something which does what my code tries to do. I know this is wrong, but hope you get the idea.

Keys: Classes that inherit from IComponent
Values: Objects of the same type like the key they are under.

Thank you for having a look :)

Comment: what's your actual problem?

Comment: That I don't know the exact syntax to achieve this.  The code above is not working: in simple words I want: `components shall be a MAP with KEYS: Class Type of classes that inherit from IComponent, VALUES: Arrays of objects of the type of the KEY`

Comment: In Java it would look like this: `Map<Class<T : GdxBehaviour>, Array<T>>` which does not work with T. It works with ? - but then I cannot be sure that the array contains the proper objects.

Comment: why do have such a map? wouldn't a plain list already suffice? You can then still do `list.filterIsInstance<T>()` if you need to... what is the purpose of such a map/list containing lots of different component instantiations when you then need some specific types?

Comment: this would indeed work. Thank you. Is there still a way to achieve what I tried?

Comment: yes... you only need to cast it, i.e. add `as T` after your `[0]`... but I can't recommend it.... note that generic type information is erased at runtime (same as in Java)... and working with unchecked casts has its own drawbacks... Try to find a more suitable data structure and or hold several lists of components if that makes sense...

Comment: instead of the `Array<*>` you can also just use `Array<IComponent>` or similar... overlooked that `*`...